# SQL query not subjected to injection, but

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

Sometimes I get this on my webserver log:

> [09-Dec-2012 15:35:45 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied
>   for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /bar/foo.php on
>   line 4

line 4 is:

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from mytablefoo ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9");
```

It looks like somebody is trying to log in using a default root username.
Any way to prevent this, even if it's not harmful?
How does he manage to connect through that line of code?

Thanks

Comment: it's weird, because the user name and pass should be the same, to the DB it's the same user(the APP) who is connecting...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at both and will keep you updated you on this page.

Comment: Is `/bar/foo.php` meant to be a publicly facing webpage? It sounds like it is included by another file, but not accessed directly by a user.

Comment: It shouldn't be directly opened by an user but it's meant to be included. I guess I'd better turn off indexing for that folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think is happening.

You have one page (e.g.: `index.php`) that includes a second page (e.g.: `/bar.foo.php`). On the `index.php`, you make the primary connection:

```
<?php
//  index.php
//  ...
$db = mysql_connect($db, $username, $password);
//  ...
```

On the second page, you do some function:

```
<?php
//  /bar/foo.php
//  ...
mysql_query("select * from mytablefoo ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9"); // TODO: use mysqli or PDO here
//  ...
```

However, there is no database connection if you visit the second file directly, so it tries connecting with default credentials, fails, and throws an error.

If you want to prevent this, then you need to secure your site. My guess is that people should never be allowed in your `/bar` folder. You can prevent people from entering this folder by adding an `.htaccess` file to this folder.

`.htaccess` files let you control how users can interact with file on your site. Just create a new text file, and save it as `.htaccess` (this file doesn't have anything before the `.`).

Put this file inside of your `/bar` folder, and put the following text inside the file:

```
deny from all
```

Now, if anyone tries to visit this folder directly, they will be shown a 403 error message instead. The PHP files can still be included by other pages.

You can learn more about `.htaccess` here:

http://perishablepress.com/stupid-htaccess-tricks/

Comment: Exactly, just what I wrote you before reading this. :) In the meanwhile I'll also switch to mysqli (I didn't know mysql_foo() was being phased out).

Answer (score 2):

The `mysql_query()` function tries to connect to the mysql server using the default username and password (configued in the php.ini) if no connection has been established yet. That is because it is supposed to run a query and if `mysql_connect()` has not been called yet, it can't.

The only thing wrong here is the PHP code. On more than one level btw.. One should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) these days.

Comment: I'll try with mysqli. It seems that the php file is manually loaded by the malicious user. However that file doesn't contain the credentials (which are included in another php file), because it's not supposed to be opened but to be included in another file where the credentials are.

Comment: i recommend blocking access with .htaccess or "define("MAIN_CODE",TRUE); // in file containing credentials" and "if(!is_defined("MAIN_CODE")) die("go away!");" // in to be included file

Answer (score 1):

This error means that this file is trying to access your database without the correct privileges in this case, using all default values without any password).

I'm going to guess that your database credentials are stored in another file. You might reference this file like this:

```
include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/filepath/db.php');
```

I know for a fact that the `$_SERVER` array is partially populated by the user that visits your website. This means that some of these variables can be empty or otherwise tampered with. For example, when a page is activated via a `CRON Job`, then this particular variable will be empty.

IIRC, it's also possible to manipulate this array by visiting the website's IP Address instead of the Domain Name (i.e.: `http://192.168.0.1/bar/foo.php` instead of `http://example.com/bar/foo.php`).

You can work around this by using the `__FILE__` variable instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`

Comment: Structure:
 
1)main php file where credentials are included().

2)mysql_query() stuff php file included() in the main php file.


My guess is that the malicious bot/user is trying to directly load the php file with mysql_query() in it, so that the credentials aren't included() yet (they are in the main php file).

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query is there has been no connection falls back to the defaults in php.ini to connect (do a phpinfo(); to see these)

The defaults are failing to connect to root and giving that error.

Agreed with Gung Foo use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

`using password: NO`  means you have no password.
try to go to admin and set a password then it will be `: YES` . 
or make assign a password to the `root`

as other said use PDO  or mysqli

Comment: I have, but after having read Chris' comment, I noticed that if you load that single file (and you're NOT supposed to do it, because the file needs to be included() elsewhere), it will lack the credentials.